# How to mimic UIButton Storyboard onClick Blink behaviour

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uibutton, storyboard

So I've noticed this slight behaviour difference between I create a UIButton in Storyboard vs Code.  When created in Storyboard, you will notice any UIButton slightly blinks in response to a users tap.

Now when I create a UIButton in code, I notice it does not do this.  My Button works fine and all, but I would like to add that same behaviour, since it is a good UI function that validates to a user that their touch was recognized.

Is there a way to add this to a UIButton created in code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using

`- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state;`  or

`- (void)setTitleColor:(UIColor *)color forState:(UIControlState)state;` or

`- (void)setTitle:(NSString *)title forState:(UIControlState)state;`

where your state may be `UIControlStateHighlighted`

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding how I can use that, but that seems like I would have to set an image for that state.  I don't have an image to set, it is a UIButton with a title text?

Comment: Aaaah, never mind.  I just used SetTitle() instead since I'm working with Label Text and that did the trick.  So I guess if I was using images that I can use SetImage().  Thanks for your help!